# Why can't I set group and ownership of one folder without afffecting the other?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, permissions, home-directory, chown

I've upgraded an Ubuntu PC from 10.04 to 12.04.

Problem is all the permissions were wrong on the home folders.

So, I  did the following:

```
sudo chown -R james:james /home/james/*
sudo chown -R james:james /home/james/.*
sudo chown -R htpc:htpc /home/htpc/*
sudo chown -R htpc:htpc /home/htpc/.*
```

But you end up with all the files in both folders either in james:james or htpc:htpc, depending on which way round you run the commands.

How have the become linked and how can I fix it?

As requested:

```
james@htpc:~$ ls -l /home
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 41 james james 4096 May 20 19:32 htpc
drwxr-xr-x 31 james james 4096 May 20 20:04 james
james@htpc:~$ ls -l /home/htpc
total 236
drwxr-xr-x  4 james james   4096 Nov 25 13:19 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 james james   4096 Mar 13  2011 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  5 james james   4096 Dec 22  2010 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 james james    179 Nov 18  2010 examples.desktop
-rwxr-xr-x  1 james james     85 Dec 27  2010 goback
-rw-r--r--  1 james james    425 Nov 28  2010 modelines
drwxr-xr-x  5 james james   4096 Dec 27  2010 Music
drwxr-xr-x 22 james james   4096 Oct 29  2012 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 james james   4096 Nov 18  2010 Public
drwxr-xr-x  2 james james   4096 Nov 18  2010 Templates
-rwxr-xr-x  1 james james    251 Dec 27  2010 testmode
drwxr-xr-x  2 james james   4096 Dec 23  2010 Videos
-rwxr-xr-x  1 james james 190672 Nov  6  2010 winetricks
james@htpc:~$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the shell is expanding the ".*" to be ".." or up one directory.

In this case it is best, IMO, to use find

Become root

```
sudo -i
```

run find

```
find /home/$user -exec chown $user:$user {} \;
```

Change $user to the appropriate user name

In theory, chown should work with the -R and without the wildcard

```
sudo chown -R $user:$user /home/$user
```

but I think this misses the hidden or .files, which is why RoboJ1M tried ".*" which caused the problem.

Comment: That worked, got some errors on a few odd files though:
`chown: cannot dereference /home/htpc/.mozilla/firefox/hsvz7dcl.default/lock: No such file or directory`
`chown: cannot access /home/james/.gvfs: Permission denied`
Some others, but they're all `cannot derefence`

Comment: Yes you will get some of those errors. Should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Each folder contains a file called `..`. This file is special in that it points to the directory containing the current working directory. For example:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/dir
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/path/to
```

Because you specified `.*` as an argument, the shell expands this to every file starting with a ".", including `..`. This means that your operation ran on everything in the current working directory, but also the parent directory (`/home`). Because you specified recursive, you changed every file and directory in your `/home` folder to whatever ownership you specified. In fact, you may have changed the owner of every single file on your system. I would recommend running `ls -l /` to check if this happened - if it did, you'll probably experience issues.

Answer (score 0):

I use this on my EC2 hosts to fix home folder permissions.

```
#fix home directories  
cd /home/  
for i in *; do   
    useradd $i  
    chown -R $i:$i /home/$i  
done
```

If you do -R you should not need to use wild cards. Just chown on the top level leave the rest alone. And as others have said .* matches ..

Comment: darn formatting....

Comment: it's not that hard ;)